# Why are mappings notated LTR despite compositition being RTL?

Tags: matrices, notation, function-and-relation-composition

Say you have the general mappings $f: S\rightarrow T$ and $g: T\rightarrow U$.
Wouldn't the notation $f: T\leftarrow S$ and $g: U\leftarrow T$ be more consistent with the right-to-left nature of composition, especially in light of how matrices are defined (taken as a linear mapping from a vector spaces $source$ to $target$, we say the height and width of the matrix is going to be $(\dim target \times \dim source)$). This convention makes chaining together matrix multiplications super straightforward, so I assume that's why it was historically chosen.

Is there a historical reason for this kind of mapping notation?

Comment: I've seen people argue that function notation (and therefore linear maps) should act on the right, but rarely "we should turn all our arrows around"...  BTW:  As far as I know, the reason is that functions act on the domain, so putting the domain farther from the function name is a little strange in its own right.

Comment: I suppose that someone once wrote f(x) and it became popular. If only they had written (x)f ......